# JHipster 8.1.0 PrimeNG icons don't appear in production

Tags: angular, jhipster, primeng, primeicons

Trying out the new JHipster 8.1.0.  I have used PrimeNG components with success in previous versions.  In the new JHipster, the PrimeNG components seem to function, but icons (primeicons) don't show up in the browser in production.

For example:

- Create a simple monolithic angular project.  I chose Gradle for the build tool, Angular front end, and MariaDB for development and production.
- Install PrimeNG packages:

```
npm i primeng
npm i primeicons
npm i @angular/animations@17.0.6
npm i @angular/cdk@17.0.5
```

- Update `vendor.scss` by adding the following:

```css
@import 'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import 'primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
@import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

- Add a PrimeNG tab component to the home page.

  - In the `home.component.ts`:

    - At the top, add: `import { TabViewModule } from 'primeng/tabview';`
    - In the `@Component` section, add `TabViewModule` to the imports
  - In the `home.component.html` HTML template, add near the top:

```html
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel header="Details" leftIcon="pi pi-id-card">In-depth details</p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Notes" leftIcon="pi pi-comment">Some lovely notes</p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Information" leftIcon="pi pi-info-circle">Additional information</p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Running the application in development (IntelliJ 2023.3.2, Java 21, Gradle 8.5, Node 18.19.0, Firefox 121.0.1), everything appears correct, and looks pretty good.

Now try it in production:

- Build the production JAR: `./gradlew -Pprod clean bootJar`
- Rename the JAR to `testapp.jar`
- Copy the JAR to the server, and launch the application: `java -jar testapp.jar`
- In a browser, navigate to the home page: `http://localhost:8080`

In production the PrimeNG tabs still work as expected **BUT** the icons don't show up.  Furthermore, in the browser console I see the following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/primeicons.ba3f916dfb64be8c.woff2  [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 8ms]
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "primeicons" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:8080/primeicons.ba3f916dfb64be8c.woff2

GET http://localhost:8080/primeicons.f8b9e8a4e401b603.woff  [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 8ms]
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "primeicons" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:8080/primeicons.f8b9e8a4e401b603.woff

GET http://localhost:8080/primeicons.0112589c5695a9ed.ttf  [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 9ms]
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "primeicons" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:3): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:8080/primeicons.0112589c5695a9ed.ttf

downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "primeicons" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:5) source: (end of source list)
```

Everything works fine in previous versions of JHipster (7.9.3 and earlier), and in development, so I'm guessing either I've missed something, done something silly, or this is a resource bundling issue in the new JHipster.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy moly, macaroni! I have an answer.

The good folks in the JHipster project have cranked up security, and lock out everything that is *not* part of their code base.  To see the `PrimeNG` `primeicons`, open `SecurityConfiguration.java`, find the `authorizeHttpRequests()` section (in my code this is around line 60), and in amongst the `.requestMatchers`, add the following:

```java
.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/*.tff"), mvc.pattern("/*.woff"), mvc.pattern("/*.woff2")).permitAll()
```

Problem solved.